# Set up a Git version control repository that integrates with OpenAtrium

Tags: version-control, distributions

Is it possible to have OpenAtrium function like the git repository on Drupal.org?

If so, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "[What theme and modules does Drupal.org use?](http://drupal.org/node/27367)" page.

Specifically for Git repository management, you'll want to use this set of modules:

- http://drupal.org/project/versioncontrol
- http://drupal.org/project/versioncontrol_git

And if you want a project release / issue tracking section like drupal.org, see:

- http://drupal.org/project/project
- http://drupal.org/project/project_issue
- http://drupal.org/project/versioncontrol_project